# MYSQL- orientacion sobre un inner join

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla (bd mysql) donde almaceno varios ID (llaves foraneas) y ahora necesito mostrar los datos vinculados a esas ID segun un valor especifico, que es un identificador.

por ejemplo, debo obtener algo asi:

```
001|identificada|soporte terreno|juanito perez|registrada|2018-04-20|detalle de incidencia
```

y en mi tabla de inidencia, la estructura es mas o menos asi:

```
id_incidencia, id_tipo,_id_soporte,id_funcionario....
```

debo usar inner join, eso lo tengo claro, el tema es que no se como hacer la consulta, tengo hasta ahora esto:

```
SELECT
id_incidencia.tbl_incidencias,
fecha_registro.tbl_incidencias,
detalle_incidencia.tbl_incidencias,
identificacion_categoria.tbl_categoria_incidencia,

FROM
tbl_incidencias
INNER JOIN tbl_categoria_incidencia.id_categoria ON = tbl_incidencias.id_categoria
WHERE
tbl_incidencias.id_registro=1
```

mipedido es si me pueden ayudar un poco en que estoy mal, o como podria encarar la consulta...

Answer (score 1):

Tu query esta al revez.  Deberia de ser asi:

```
SELECT
tbl_incidencias.id_incidencia,
tbl_incidencias.fecha_registro,
tbl_incidencias.detalle_incidencia,
tbl_categoria_incidencia.identificacion_categoria,

FROM
tbl_incidencias
INNER JOIN tbl_categoria_incidencia ON tbl_categoria_incidencia.identificacion_categoria= 
tbl_incidencias.id_categoria
WHERE
tbl_incidencias.id_registro=1
```

Puedes ver mas en la [Documentacion de MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

Comment: Creo que el inner join esta correcto, simplemente tenia la parte de el SELECT al revez.

Comment: mmmm me da error igual....en el select hay algo mal? probe dandolo vuelta y tampoco

Comment: Tienes razon, ya edite mi respuesta

Comment: ahi consegui algo, me queda el where que no me funciona, como debria usar el where en este caso, considerando que debo traer todos los registros de un funcionario x(id_registro) que esta en la tabla incidencias como llave foranea y como pk en la tabla funcionarios

Comment: Simplemente añade WHERE func.id_registro = 'tu valor'.  Pero eso es otra pregunta.  Si esta respuesta te funciono marcala como correcta.

Comment: hola @alanfcm, he estado toda la tarde peliando con la consulta, y con el where como me recomiendas tampoco consigo traer todos los datos, solo me trae uno

Comment: Creo que estas confundido.  Si añades el WHERE, se supone que solo te traiga un registro, sin el WHERE te trae todos.

Answer (score 0):

Logre esto:

```
SELECT 
inc.id_incidencia,
inc.fecha_registro,
ingr.identificacion_metodo,
est.identificacion_estado,
tip.identificacion_solicitud,
niv.identificacion_nivel,
fun.nombre_funcionario,
func.id_registro,
inc.detalle_incidencia

FROM tbl_incidencias inc 
INNER JOIN tbl_niveles_incidencia niv ON inc.id_nivel=niv.id_nivel/* verifica el nivel de la incidencia*/
INNER JOIN tbl_tipo_solicitud tip ON inc.id_tipo_solicitud=tip.id_tipo_solicitud/*verifica el tipo de solicitud*/
INNER JOIN tbl_funcionario_soporte fun ON inc.id_registro_soporte=fun.id_registro_soporte
INNER JOIN tbl_estados_incidencia est ON inc.id_estado=est.id_estado
INNER JOIN tbl_metodos_ingreso_incidencia ingr ON inc.id_metodo_ingreso=ingr.id_metodo_ingreso
```

Me trae los campos ok, pero tengo que añadirle un `where` que me traiga todos los registros segun el `id_registro`, ahi me pierdo...